# RecyclerView item style applying to all items after filter

Tags: android, arraylist, filter, android-recyclerview, searchview

I'm having a little problem with a `RecyclerView`.

On the method `OnBindViewHolder` of it's `Adapter` I'm making a test, to define or not if the item of the `RecyclerView` should use a custom background color.

Up to this point everything is working fine, the problem is, after using a filter with a `SearchView` if I filter the one result with the custom background color, after cleaning the filter/collapse the `SearchView`, all other items are getting the same background color.

Here is some code from my adapter:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder (MyAdapter.VieHolder holder, int position){

    holder.textViewName.setText(myVisibleList.get(position).getName());
    // myVisibleList is the list that is show in the recyclerView

    // If true, is birthday, then change the item background color
    if(myVisibleList.get(position).isBirthDay){

        holder.layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.recycler_view_selector_colored_item);

    }

}

@Override
public Filter getFilter(){return null;}

public void setFilter(String query){

    myVisibleList = new ArrayList<>();

    // Contact is the object show in the recyclerView / allContacts is the list if all the contacts
    for (Contact c : allContacts){

    if(c.getName().contains(query)){

        myVisibleList.add(c);

    }

    }

    notifyDataSetChanged();

}

// Method to clear the filter / Called when the searchView is closed
public void clearFilter(){

    myVisibleList = new ArrayList<>();
    myVisibleList.addAll(allContacts);
    notifyDataSetChanged

}
```

Comment: i think your problem is in this line of code .. holder.layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.recycler_view_selector_colored_item);  because it sets the color to the whole layout (whatever the layout is )

Comment: This `layout` is a `RelativeLayout` which holds the `TextViews` of the item. But I'm gonna look into it right now, thanks for the answer.

Comment: Nope, it didn't work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you need to add an else clause here:

```
if (myVisibleList.get(position).isBirthDay){
    holder.layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.recycler_view_selector_colored_item);
} else {
    holder.layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.my_default_recycler_view_color_item); 
    // or holder.layout.setBackgroundResource(0);   
}
```

See [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource(int)) where it says that

> 0 [is] to remove the background

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks, It worked just fine. I thought that maybe I could do it without having to redefine the layout but this way works fine.

Comment: @MidasLefko Looks good, but it's amazing to me that almost every article on RecyclerViews has its focus on creating a list, but none on saving the list. It does no good to create a beautifully crafted/valuable list (say a big list of songs I want to download) and then have the list literally be destroyed if I navigate away from the list with the single press of the back button. Why wouldn't saving state code be a requirement for creating every RecyclerView list just like the other requirements: the adapter, the layoutmanager, onCreateViewHolder, onBindViewHolder and getItemCount?  Thoughts?